# Trouble with pulling information from data provider/JSON (ionic framework)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm still new to angular and ionic, and I'm trying to make a pokedex app. I created a json file with an array of "pocket monsters". As of right now, I'm trying to just pull the information out of the json file and display it, but I'm unsuccessful. When I run the application, it just shows a list with numbers. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help out? I'll add the data provider, json file, and the home component and template for reference.

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Pokedex
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let pocketMonster of pocketMonsters; let i = index;">
      <ion-label>{{i+1}}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
  

  <!--<div *ngIf="pocketMonsters.length"></div> -->

</ion-content>
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { pokemonDataService } from '../../providers/data/data';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

  pocketMonsters = [];
  searchQuery: string = '';

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public dataService: pokemonDataService) {

   
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    
           
    
           this.dataService.getAllPokemon().then((data) => {
    
               data.map((pocketMonster) => {

                   
                   return pocketMonster;
    
               });    
    
               this.pocketMonsters = data;
    
           });
    
       }

  //ngOnInit(){
    //this.dataService.getAllPokemon()
      //.subscribe(data => {
        //this.pokemonList = data;
    //});
  //}

  

}
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';



@Injectable()
export class pokemonDataService {
 
    data: any;
 
    constructor(public http: Http) {
 
    }

    getAllPokemon() {
      if(this.data){
        return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => {

        this.http.get('assets/data/pokemon.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data.pocketMonsters;
            resolve(this.data);
        });

    });
      }
 
    
 
}
```

```js
{
    "pocketMonsters": [

        {
            "pokemonName" : "Bulbasaur",
            "pokedexNumber" : "001",
            "description": "Bulbasaur can be seen napping in bright sunlight. There is a seed on its back. By soaking up the sun's rays, the seed grows progressively larger",
            "pokemonImage" : "<img src='assets/imgs/bulbasaur.png"

        },

        {
            "pokemonName" : "Ivysaur",
            "pokedexNumber" : "002",
            "description" : "",
            "pokemonImage" : "<img src='assets/imgs/ivysaur.png"
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem. I can do {{pocketMonster....}} to access what I need from each object. Example: {{pocketMonster.pokemonName}}.

Answer (score 0):

you are returning function  so it does not work

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { pokemonDataService } from '../../providers/data/data';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
  pocketMonsters = [];
  searchQuery: string = '';

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public dataService:pokemonDataService) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {    
       this.dataService.getAllPokemon().then((data) => {    
           data.map((pocketMonster) => {
           > this.pocketMonsters = data;
               return pocketMonster;    
           });    
       });    
   }
}
```

Comment: this.pocketMonsters = data; place upper than returning the function

Comment: I tried that, but it's still just displaying a list of nothing but numbers 1-9. How do I display each attribute for each pokemon from the json file? For example: pokemonName, description, etc?

Comment: show me result of 
console.log(this.pocketMonsters)

Comment: It looks like it's pulling the data out of the json, I just have to figure out how to parse it out. Here's the console.log:                                                               0
:
{pokemonName: "Bulbasaur", pokedexNumber: "001", description: "Bulbasaur can be seen napping in bright sunlight. …e sun's rays, the seed grows progressively larger", pokemonImage: "<img src='assets/imgs/bulbasaur.png"}
1
:
{pokemonName: "Ivysaur", pokedexNumber: "002", description: "", pokemonImage: "<img src='assets/imgs/ivysaur.png"}

Comment: if you can give me your teamviewer than i can help you out